# Limit access to dav SVN to valid-users

Tags: apache, svn, mod-dav-svn

I tried to limit my svn repository with [this manual](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Subversion_unter_Debian_mit_Webaccess#Erstellen_des_Repositories):

This is my `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf`:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/lib/svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz

  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>

  # SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

and this my `/etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz` :

```
[/]
* = r
testuser = rw
testuser2 = rw
...
```

this gives read access to everybody, and now **there isn't any popup that would ask for my username**.

And how would I have to configure it, so noone has read access but  valid-users?

What am I missing?

Comment: take out the `* = r` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LimitExcept](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept)** is only needed if you want to limit certain paths separately:

this will work:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/lib/svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz

  Require valid-user

  # SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```